# Are these conditions enough to recognize an extension method in an expression tree?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, expression-trees

I looked an the `MethodCallExpression` object for extension method and found that

- the `Object` property is `null` and
- the `Arguments[0].NodeType` is `MemberAccess`

are those two parameters enough to say that this method call is an extension method?

---

Here's some test code (updated):

*as @Rob suggested it might be just a static method and indeed there is no differce between those two calls*

```
void Main()
{
    var abc = "abc";
    Bar(() => abc.Foo());
    Bar(() => Baz(abc));
}

static void Bar<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)
{
    var methodCallExpression = expr.Body as MethodCallExpression;
}

static string Baz(string s)
{
    return "baz";
}

static class Ext
{
    public static string Foo(this string s)
    {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily, it could just be a static method.

Comment: @Rob Not just could be.  It *must always* be.

Comment: @Servy Well yeah, but I meant it in the sense of "It could just be a static method, not necessarily a static extension method"

Comment: @Rob you're right, there no difference with static methods ;-( so I guess I need another indicator.

Comment: I marked it myself as a duplicate. I was looking at the wrong place ;-)